# How to Perform Full Power Cycle on Reboot

Tags: motherboard, pci-express

Hopefully this is the place to ask this. My problem is that I have a PCIe device I'm trying to use on a home built computer. The card will only work on a full power cycle of the computer. I've tried this card on multiple motherboards and with many BIOS configurations, but no change. It only works on a hard shutdown and power up.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10, and oddly enough sometimes the card will work on reboot when I restart from Windows 7. Same hardware. But this happens only rarely. Is there a way I can perform a `reboot` command, and have the power get fully cycled?

If I can't reconfigure the reboot to do a full power cycle, is there any way from the OS side to actually cycle power to a PCIe slot while the machine is on? I'm thinking that is a long shot.

Some info about my system (s)

Motherboard: ASUS P8 Z77 / ASROCK Z68M-ITX-HT / ASROCK Z77 Extreme

CPU: i7 3770K

Ram: 32Gb Corsair

Power Supply: Corsair HX 1050

PCIe device is a frame grabber to operate an industrial scientific camera

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `man bootparam`:

> `'reboot=[warm|cold][,[bios|hard]]'`
>
> Since Linux 2.0.22, a reboot is by default a cold reboot.  One asks for the old default with 'reboot=warm'.  (A cold reboot may be required to reset certain hardware, but might destroy not yet written data in a disk cache.  A warm reboot may be faster.)  By default, a reboot is hard, by asking the keyboard controller to pulse the reset line low, but there is at least one type of motherboard where that doesn't work.  The option 'reboot=bios' will instead jump through the BIOS.

1. You can edit `/etc/default/grub`, update `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` variable, for example:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="reboot=hard"
```

2. then execute command

```
sudo update-grub
```

3. and then reboot.
4. You can check your current kernel arguments by command:

```
cat /proc/cmdline
```